# Is there a way to put JPanel on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm trying to put a JPanel inside OR on a JPanel, whichever may be the case, ultimately I just want this to work like this
[image: Insanely well painted description of the problem]

As you can see on the picture, the red line is a JFrame and it has 2 JPanels inside it, on the green JPanel there are some different JPanels.

I need help with the green JPanel and the little JPanels inside it. Is there any way to make it work like this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**==============EDIT 1==============**

So here is some code, to show you what I've done so far with the help of @hfontanez.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //JFrame
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setSize(1920, 1080);
        jframe.setResizable(false);
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        //parentJpanel   -   This is the main panel
        JPanel parentJpanel = new JPanel();
        parentJpanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        parentJpanel.setSize(1920, 1080);
        parentJpanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //smallPanel    -   This is the little panel on the bottom
        JPanel smallPanel = new JPanel();
        smallPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        smallPanel.setSize(1920, 300);
        smallPanel.setLocation(0, 780);
        smallPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(smallPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        parentJpanel.add(smallPanel);
        jframe.add(parentJpanel);
    }
}
```

[image: The result of the code below]

I expected the top part to be yellow, and the small part on the bottom to be green, yet the whoel thing turned green. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Remember I told you, you need to understand how layout managers behave. In order for a particular panel to be of a certain size that the layout manager "respects", you cannot use `setSize` function. You must use `setDimension` instead if I am not mistaken. I haven't done Java Swing in almost 10 years, but I am pretty certain of this. Read more about layout managers for the correct solution.

Comment: @hfontanez I see, but there is no `setDimension` on `JPanel`'s nor on `JFrame`'s, anyhow I'll start to look into layout managers, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The pictured GUI is created using three panels.

1. The `YELLOW` panel is the game play area. It has no layout, no components (which define their own preferred sizes) and is custom painted, so it defines a sensible preferred size to report to the layout manager.
2. The `GREEN` panel contains controls. It uses a `FlowLayout`.
3. The `RED` panel uses a `BorderLayout`, and puts the `YELLOW` panel in the `CENTER` and the `GREEN` panel in the `PAGE_END`.

### Code

This is the code that made the screenshot seen above.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameLayout {

    GameLayout() {
        // The main GUI. Everything else is added to this panel
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        gui.setBackground(Color.RED);

        // The custom painted area - it is a panel that defines its preferred size.
        gui.add(new GamePanel());

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        for (int ii = 1; ii<5; ii++) {
            buttonPanel.add(new JButton("B " + ii));
        }
        gui.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Game Layout");
        f.setContentPane(gui);
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> new GameLayout();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    GamePanel() {
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `LayoutManager` so when you put the `JPanel` inside the other `JPanel` it will have the correct look. If you simply put panels inside the others, the parent JPanel will use its default layout manager, which is `FlowLayout`.

For the look of it, it seems you need to use [Border Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for the parent (yellow) panel. For the green, you have options, but I think your best bet is to use [Box Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) with a *PAGE_AXIS* Component Orientation.

In general, you need to be familiarized with two things: 1) Layout Managers and how they behave, and 2) the default layout behavior of JComponents.

Comment: So what LayoutShould I add to the `JFrame`? I'm asking this because when I did as you said the green panel just filled the whole `JPanel` even when I changed the `setSize()` value to some small `Dimension`